# assign column entry to a planner bucket

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, microsoft-planner

I am setting up this flow. When a SP new entry create a planner task.

The issue I have is that on the planner I have buckets set by location. The entry column on SP is site.
I need to send actions from site1 to bucket location1, site2 to bucket location2.

I have set the flow, but I am stuck on how to assign to a bucket.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple conditions and actions required to achieve flow